# Shortcut keys and other issues with certain gtk apps on Wayland

Tags: shortcut-keys, gtk, 17.10, wayland

It seems a very common issue and I'm stunned reading that WON'T FIX!

Briefly, I noted that global shortcut keys (such as Ctrl+Space I use to call my favourite launcher) doesn't work when focus is on certain applications windows (gnome-terminal or gedit, for example) but only when I'm running Wayland.

Moreover, if I use xfce4-panel and the window buttons element, the button won't appear for the same apps.

With other apps (chromium, thunderbird, synapse, for example) both issues are not presenting.

https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/issues/309

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1214318

Comment: Welcome to Wayland =) It is up to developers what features they wish to implement with wayland and not much you can do about it. You can sometimes find extensions for gnome or write your own (advantage of gnome it is possible for mere mortals to write js or css and change gnome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what do you want to say?

Bug with global shortcuts is known on [launchpad as bug 1244090](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090).

Keyboard bug for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and so on is reported to [launchpad as bug 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473).

Also there is another problem with non-latin shortcuts - it is known as [launchpad bug 1226962](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962).

Also users want to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> as keyboard layout switcher [as in launchpad bug 1218322](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1218322) but can do this only from GNOME Tweaks.

Myself I found only one resolution - I'll stay on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE until 2021 year ([really 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) because it's Ubuntu flavor).

Comment: Avoiding wayland is reasonable, but it is the way of the future as X is going to be supported less and less, but transition will take years.

Comment: @Panther **November 5, 2010** Ubuntu shocks the world announcing it is witching off **X** and moving to **Wayland**.  So you are right, *transition will take years*: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2469498/desktop-apps/ubuntu-abandons-x-server-for-wayland.html