# do not work ctrl+shift+v

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

The problem is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> do not work in eclipse or thunderbird when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is set for changing layout. It is true as for ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04. 
thank you for advices!

Comment: Also see bug links in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968105/66509).